# Access function parametrization in class top level code

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest allows to parametrize all the tests defined in a class by applying the parametrize decorator at the class level : following [the documentation example](https://pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/parametrize.html), defining

```py
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize("n,expected", [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
class TestClass:
    def test_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert n + 1 == expected
    def test_weird_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert (n * 1) + 1 == expected
```

allows to access `n` and `expected` within the tests.

What is also possible is to put some code at the class level, which will be executed for each test and is thus usefull to setup the tests :

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("n,expected", [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
class TestClass:
    #This code is run before each test :
    with open("file.dat") as f:
       expected_result = f.readlines()

    def test_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert n + 1 == expected
    def test_weird_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert (n * 1) + 1 == expected
```

Howerver, it seems to be impossible to access the parametrized arguments in this specific block :

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("n,expected", [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
class TestClass:
    #This code is run before each test :
    with open("file.dat") as f:
       expected_result = f.readlines()
    assert n < 10

    def test_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert n + 1 == expected
    def test_weird_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert (n * 1) + 1 == expected
```

produces the exception : `E   NameError: name 'n' is not defined`

I would like to use the parametrized arguments for test setup : is there any way to access it at class level ?

Comment: No, you cannot access parameter like that.
alternatives:
1. use `setup_class(cls)` to setup parameters instead of `parametrize`decorator. 
2. use fixture to provide parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the code in a `@pytest.fixture`, this will allow you to access the tests parameters

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("n,expected", [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
class TestClass:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
    def setup_and_teardown(self, n):
        with open("file.dat") as f:
            self.expected_result = f.readlines()
        assert n < 10
        yield

    def test_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert n + 1 == expected

    def test_weird_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert (n * 1) + 1 == expected
```

This will also support different parameters values for each test

```
class TestClass:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
    def setup_and_teardown(self, n):
        with open("file.dat") as f:
            self.expected_result = f.readlines()
        yield

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("n,expected", [(1, 2)])
    def test_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert n + 1 == expected

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("n,expected", [(3, 4)])
    def test_weird_simple_case(self, n, expected):
        assert (n * 1) + 1 == expected
```

Comment: The fixture seems to work, but if an assert fails in the setup_and_teardown code, pytest just skip the test instead of reporting it as failed. Can this be changed ?

Comment: @Juklaa in that case the test is marked with error `test setup failed`. What exactly are you looking for to happen?

Comment: I may have miss something, but with your code, adding `assert False` in the setup_and_teardown method leads to "no tests ran in 0.12s" ; I was expected the test to fail

Comment: @Juklaa I get `______________ ERROR at setup of TestClass.test_simple_case[1-2] ______________

self = <Example_test.TestClass object at 0x0000025D2C869A30>, n = 1

    @pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
    def setup_and_teardown(self, n):
>       assert n < 0
E       assert 1 < 0

___________ ERROR at setup of TestClass.test_weird_simple_case[3-4] ___________

    @pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
    def setup_and_teardown(self, n):
>       assert n < 0
E       assert 3 < 0`

Comment: How do you ran the tests and what is your pytest version?

Comment: You are right, I tried to re-run this in a clean environment (python3 -m pytest test_sample.py) and I got he error. I guess there is a problem in my configuration, I will try to figure it out